# Is there a way to access this.value (of an input) from within a function call in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an HTML input for which I want to limit the possible to 100 when manually entering, I have a min and a max so that if they use the spinner (up and down arrows) it limits it already. To do this, instead of using Inline Javascript, I wanted to call a function that could be used for several functions throughout my HTML file.

Wanted Functionality:

```
<input id="..." oninput="foo()">
...
<script>
function foo() {
   if(this.value > 100) {
      this.value = 100;    // If the inputted value is 99, do nothing, if it's 999, change it to 100
   }
}
</script>
```

I wanted a functionality like this, which would let me this this.value - however - this.value is not accessible (I think???) from within the foo function.

So I tried doing this:

```
<input id="..." oninput="foo(this.value)">
...
<script>
function foo(value) {
   if(value > 100) {
      value = 100;
   }
}
</script>
```

But I think only the "copy" of value gets changed to 100, not the actual value. So I was able to do it by returning a value like this:

```
<input id="..." oninput="this.value = foo(this.value)">
...
<script>
function foo(value) {
   if(value > 100) {
      value = 100;
   }
   return value;
}
</script>
```

but this code seems quite clumsy, is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT**: SOLVED! Thank you all for the answers, this is my code now! I also parse the input to make sure that it's ONLY numbers, no "e" or "." because all I care about are integers.

```
<input id="area-level-input" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="100" oninput="limitInput.call(this, 100)" onkeydown="isValidNumberEntry()">
```

Where the respective functions are:

```
function limitInput(limit) {
    if(this.value > limit) {
        this.value = limit;
    }
}


function isValidNumberEntry() {
    // keyCode 8: Backspace; keyCode 46: Delete
    return (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) ? true : !isNaN(Number(event.key));
}
```

Comment: `<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" />` ?

Comment: Don't use inline JS for this. Have a look at `Element.addEventListener()`

Comment: _is there a better way to do this?_ - look at the first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
<input id="..." oninput="foo.call(this)">
...
<script>
function foo() {
   if(this.value > 100) {
      this.value = 100;    // If the inputted value is 99, do nothing, if it's 999, change it to 100
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to accomplish what you are trying:

- Passing *this* to the inline function
- Passing *event* to the inline function

Both have the same outcome and will function as you'd expect:

```
<input oninput="foo(this)"/>
```

or

```
<input oninput="foo(event)"/>
```

then your function can be:

```
function foo(thisChoice) {

  if(thisChoice.value > 100) {
      thisChoice.value = 100;
   }

}
```

or

```
function foo(eventChoice) {

  if(eventChoice.target.value > 100) {
      eventChoice.target.value = 100;
   }

}
```

Bear in mind that one you are passing only the input tag, and the other you are passing the entire Event to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct.

You could modify the value of the element directly in the function to make it a bit more readable and reusable. For example:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="100" oninput="limitTo(100, this)" />
<script>
  function limitTo(upperLimit, el) {
    if (el.value > upperLimit) {
      el.value = upperLimit;
    }
  }
</script>
```

I also suggest to set the `type` attribute of the input element to `number`.
The advantage is that the browser will make sure to accept only digits, and it allows to set the attribute [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#max).